# drupal 6 table theme() output

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am making a drupal table and looked up drupal_theme() and tried to follow the rules for constructing the table with the following code:

```
  $data = array('value', 'values');
  $header = array ($data);
  $rows = array(
    // Simple row
    array(
      'Cell 1', 'Cell 2', 'Cell 3'
    ),
    // Row with attributes on the row and some of its cells.
    array(
      'data' => array('Cell 1', array('data' => 'Cell 2', 'colspan' => 2)),
      'class' => 'funky'
    )
      );
  
  //$output = theme('table', $header, $rows, $attributes = array(), 
  //$caption = NULL);
  $table_t = theme_table($header, $rows, $attributes = array(), $caption = NULL);
  //return $output;
  return $table_t;
```

However, the table doesn't contain row and column headers like i expected. whats wrong??

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Also, consider asking on http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Watki02 Not to be picky but cross-site posting isn't allowed, it'd be great if you could let people know they need to flag for migration if they want the question on another site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help, but this is code for the table headers I use in one of my modules.

```
  $header = array(
    array('data' => t('One')),
    array('data' => t('Two')),
    array('data' => t('Three')),
    array('data' => t('Four')),
  );
```

See if that works for you.

Also, `theme_table($header, $rows, $attributes = array(), $caption = NULL)` can just be `theme_table($header, $rows)`

Comment: You're right on both accounts. After replacing the $header with your code, the column names one, two, three, four are listed. Also attributes and caption are not needed. As for Row headers, I was wondering if you know about that? Thank you :)

Comment: the best thing i can think of is assigning fow values from column 1 to be the row labels, so array('data' => array('row1','value','value'),'data'=> array('row2','value','value')); etc...

Comment: I don't think the table theme function supports anything for row headers (maybe row markers is a better term). The best I can think of is to make the first column with a blank header, then give a class to the first cell in each row that you then either provide your own style to, or set the class to the same as the header cells. Just play around with it and ask another question if necessary so you'll get some more eyeballs looking at it.